# How to properly initialize array of structures inside another structure and return it from function?

Tags: c, c99

I have an array of such structures:

```
typedef struct month {
    char cName[20];
    char cAbbr[20];
    int iDays;
    int iNumber;
} MONTH;
```

which is nested in another structure:

```
typedef struct input{
    MONTH * pMonths;
    DATE sDate;
    CALCS sCalcs;
} INPUT;
```

I initialize this array of structs in stack like that:

```
MONTH * init_months(bool bLeap) {

    MONTH months[NUM_MONTHS] = {
        { .cName = "January", .cAbbr = "Jan", .iDays = 31, .iNumber = 1 },
        { "February", "Feb", 28, 2 },
        { "March", "Mar", 31, 3 },
        { "April", "Apr", 30, 4 },
        { "May", "May", 31, 5 },
        { "June", "Jun", 30, 6 },
        { "July", "Jul", 31, 7 },
        { "August", "Aug", 31, 8 },
        { "September", "Sep", 30, 9 },
        { "October", "Oct", 31, 10 },
        { "November", "Nov", 30, 11 },
        { "December", "Dec", 31, 12 }
    };

    if(bLeap){
        months[1].iDays++;
    }

    return months;
}
```

The question is, if i form a **INPUT** structure inside some function:

```
INPUT GetUserInput(void){

    // init months
    MONTH * pMonths;
    pMonths = init_months(isLeap(sDate.iYear));

    // some code here
    ...
    INPUT sInput = { pMonths, sDate, sCalcs };

    // return
    return sInput;
}
```

then how to properly initialize array of **MONTH** and/or how to properly initialize **INPUT** so it would contain valid data when returned from **GetUserInput()** ?

Comment: `return months;` attempts to return an array that is local to `init_months()`. When you declare `MONTH months[NUM_MONTHS] = {...}` it is created with *automatic storage duration* that ends when the function returns. (the memory resides on the function stack which is released for re-use on return) You can allocate for 12 `struct month` and `memcpy()` from `months` to the allocated block and return the pointer to the allocated block of memory which has *allocated storage duration* that extends until `free()` is called on the block of memory.

Comment: Another option is to change `MONTH * pMonths;` to `MONTH Months[12];` and then you can change `MONTH * init_months(bool bLeap)` to `INPUT init_months(bool bLeap)` and populate the array within the struct within `int_months()` and return the struct (a function can always return its own type)

Comment: whats the difference between two options?

Comment: In the first you dynamically allocate for `MONTHS *pmonths = malloc (12 * sizeof *pmonths);` in `MONTH * init_months(bool bLeap)` and `memcpy()` `months` to `pmonths` and return `pmonths`. In the second, you change the pointer `pmonths` to an array in `struct input` and you make the function return  type `INPUT`. You can populate the array within the struct and then return the struct.

Comment: Here is [An Example of the 2nd Option](https://paste.opensuse.org/55926397) (link good 30 days) Note `DATE` and `CALCS` types were change to `int` for the purpose of the example (you didn't provide declarations for either)

Comment: but the only way to return an array from function is to dynamically allocate it hence return a pointer. so in 2nd option you still create array on the stack and return it in structure. why this is allowed?

Comment: There is a caveat. You are not returning an "array" on its own. The array is contained within a struct. In that case the compiler reserves bytes for the total struct so it can be returned. (just like it would reserve space for an `int` or `float` and allow you to return those types. There is no "array type" function. On access an array is converted to a pointer to the first element. So a function that attempts to return an array is in actuality returning a pointer. (where only memory for the pointer is returned -- the array would be destroyed and your pointer would point nowhere)

Comment: Either way you want to do it is fine (option 1, option 2). If you want to handle the array alone -- then option 1 - dynamically allocate and copy is the way to go.

Comment: Thats very interesting, thanks a lot, i'll try both :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1. Make it static (but all returned references will reference the same array).

```
    static MONTH months[NUM_MONTHS] = {
```

2. Use malloc and compound literal

```
    MONTH *months = malloc(sizeof(*months) * NUM_MONTHS);
    
    /* check if memory was allocated */
    
    memcpy(months, (MONTH[]){
        { .cName = "January", .cAbbr = "Jan", .iDays = 31, .iNumber = 1 },
        { "February", "Feb", 28, 2 },
        { "March", "Mar", 31, 3 },
        { "April", "Apr", 30, 4 },
        { "May", "May", 31, 5 },
        { "June", "Jun", 30, 6 },
        { "July", "Jul", 31, 7 },
        { "August", "Aug", 31, 8 },
        { "September", "Sep", 30, 9 },
        { "October", "Oct", 31, 10 },
        { "November", "Nov", 30, 11 },
        { "December", "Dec", 31, 12 }}, sizeof(*months) * NUM_MONTHS);
```

3. Wrap the table into another structure and return by value

```
typedef struct
{
    MONTH months[NUM_MONTHS];
}YEAR;

YEAR init_months(bool bLeap) {

    YEAR year = {{
        { .cName = "January", .cAbbr = "Jan", .iDays = 31, .iNumber = 1 },
        { "February", "Feb", 28, 2 },
        { "March", "Mar", 31, 3 },
        { "April", "Apr", 30, 4 },
        { "May", "May", 31, 5 },
        { "June", "Jun", 30, 6 },
        { "July", "Jul", 31, 7 },
        { "August", "Aug", 31, 8 },
        { "September", "Sep", 30, 9 },
        { "October", "Oct", 31, 10 },
        { "November", "Nov", 30, 11 },
        { "December", "Dec", 31, 12 }}};

    if(bLeap){
        year.months[1].iDays++;
    }

    return year;
}
```